# Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Space\Find\index.php on line 21

Tags: php

```
<?php 

    $offset = 0;

    if ( isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['searchfor']) && isset($_POST['replacewith']) ) {
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        $searchfor = $_POST['searchfor'];
        $replacewith = $_POST['replacewith'];

        $search_length = strlen($searchfor);

        if (!empty($text) && !empty($searchfor) && !empty($replacewith)) {

            while ($stringpos = strpos($text, $searchfor, $offset)) {
                echo $stringpos.'<br/>';
                echo $offset = $stringpos + $search_length.'<br/>';
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "There Mustn't be any Void Space in the Field.";
        }
    }

?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="text" placeholder="Enter the MSG here" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="searchfor" class="search" placeholder="Search for"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="replacewith" class="replace" placeholder="Replace with"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Find and Replace">
</form>
```

This is where I'm having problem getting an error whenever I'm putting value for search.

```
while ($stringpos = strpos($text, $searchfor, $offset))
```

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Space\Find\index.php on line 21

anyone please help me out here any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$offset is supposed to be numerical, but you are assigning a string to it in the while itself:

```
echo $offset = $stringpos + $search_length.'<br/>';
```

After this line, `$offset` is no longer a number and the second time the while is executed, you'd get that notice

Comment: If OP Needs it to be a string for whatever reason, he can go around the route of type conversion also

Answer (score 0):

```php
while($strpos=strpos($text,$search,(int)($offset))){
    echo $offset=($strpos+$search_length)."<br>";
}
```

Need a type casting in while loop... `(int)($offset)`
That's it.