# I want the radio button to be disabled after being used eight times

Tags: php

```html
<?php 
for ($x = 8; $x < 0; $x--) {
    <input type="radio" name="day"
<?php if (isset($day) && $day=="monday") echo "checked";?>
value="mon">Monday 08:30 AM - 10:30 AM <br>;
} 
?>
```

I want the radio button work eight times and then be disabled

Comment: Do you need 8 radio buttons or just one radio button than can only be clicked 8 times? Maybe add some more information in your question as to what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: a radio button that can be clicked 8 times

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    session_start();

    // store count result in SESSION

    if (isset($_SESSION['count_days']) && !empty($_SESSION['count_days'])) {
        // if there is already quantity of days
        $count_days = $_SESSION['count_days'];
    } else {
        // or there are no days yet
        $count_days = 0;
    }
    // after data posted look if radio was checked
    if (isset($_POST['day'])) {
        $day = $_POST['day'];
    } else {
        $day = 0;
    }

    $count_days += $day;

    // save quanitity in SESSION
    $_SESSION['count_days'] = $count_days;

    if ($count_days == 8) {
        $checkbox_status = ' disabled';
    } else {
        $checkbox_status = '';
    }

//  echo $count_days;

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Checkbox1 <input type="radio" name="day" value="1"<?php echo $checkbox_status; ?>>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\DEATH STAR\form\form.php on line 37

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641110/notice-a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered-in-c-xampp-htdocs-space-fin Maybe this can help you.

Comment: it works ;I  still get the warning message,and the counter resets when the session ends

Comment: can some one else help

Comment: Of course counter will reset if session ends, if you want to store result even after closing browser, you need to use COOKIE or something else.

Comment: is there a way to use the database instead of cookies

Comment: You can use anything you want, it depends on what do you want.